# Call Google API from javascript code

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I want to call the Google API from JavaScript code.

I have a URL to search nearby locations like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=ww.www,yy.yyy&radius=50&key=XXXXX
```

When I run that through browser I get the correct JSON result.

But I want to get the JSON response from my JavaScript code.

I don't want to show these locations in Google Maps, just to get the JSON object and manipulate it according to my needs.

I tried to send it via an Ajax call, but it gives an error.

Comment: What's the error you're getting ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I am using:

```
//remember to add your API KEY to the url below. 

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=UK&key=<KEY-GOES-HERE>', 
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res.status); //responds with "OK"
    }
});
```

You will need to use the jQuery tag for it to function, as its using the jQuery ajax function:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the places-library of the Maps-Javascript-API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

You may use the nearbySearch of this library also without a map(but when you print data without a map you must include the [Logo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#LogoRequirements))

The URL you've posted may not be requested via AJAX, because the server doesn't send the appropriate headers for a XDomainRequest